# Completable Future Suggestion needed

Tags: java, completable-future

i am new to CompletableFutures and need some to help better understand this topic. Trying to implement a personal project where i write a service to read some data from the mysql sakila db. Here is the db schema : [enter link description here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-structure.html)

Here is what i am trying to achieve :

1.) CompletableFuture to Load a Film object by id.
2.) If it doesnt exist then dont proceed.
3.) If it exists then load : Categories , Languages in parallel and update Category Names and Language Name in the Film object returned at 1.)

While i can do it using thenApply , i would ideally like to load : the filmCategories ,categories and languages in parallel and then merge the data into my dto.

Any help would be appreciated

```
    CompletableFuture<Map<Integer,String>> categories = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
            () -> categoryService.getCategories().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(CategoryDto::getCategoryId,CategoryDto::getCategoryName))

    ) ;

    CompletableFuture<Map<Integer,String>> languages = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
            () -> languageService.getLanguages().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(LanguageDto::getLanguageId,LanguageDto::getLanguageName))
    ) ;

    CompletableFuture<Map<Integer,List<FilmCategoryDto>>> filmCategories = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
            () -> filmCategoryRepository.findFilmCategoryEntitiesByFilmId(filmId)
                    .stream().map(
                            e -> {
                                FilmCategoryDto filmCategoryDto = mapper.filmCategoryToFilmCategoryDto(e);
                                filmCategoryDto.setCategoryName(categories.join().get(filmCategoryDto.getCategoryId()));
                                return filmCategoryDto;
                            }

                    )
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(FilmCategoryDto::getFilmId))
    ) ;

    CompletableFuture.allOf(filmCategories,languages).join();
    return filmRepository.findById(filmId)
            .map(e -> {
                FilmDto f = mapper.filmToFilmDto(e);
                f.setLanguageName(languages.join().get(f.getLanguageId()));
                f.setFilmCategories(filmCategories.join().get(f.getFilmId()));
                return f;
            })
            .orElse(null);
```

Comment: You are using the wrong tool for the job. Tell the database to join the data before returning.

Comment: @Holger : You are right but this is a learning exercise. Hence the question.  I wanted to see how this could be achieved in CompletableFuture.

Comment: Well, learning exercises should also be designed to help learning the right approach. Anyway, one thing to learn, your code becomes more readable when you replace `() -> { return expression; }` with `() -> expression`. Further, learn that there are more methods than `thenApply`. For example, `thenAccept`, to perform an action which doesn’t have to produce a result or `thenAcceptBoth` for an action depending on two inputs. Study [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) to find out what the class offers…

Comment: @Holger: Hope you can chime in. I updated my code. My thinking is that allOff can load all dependent reference data in parallel. And i can create my object once allOff is done, Do you see any issues with this approach ?

Comment: This seems to be a common confusion. `allOf` does not influence the processing of the inputs at all. The operations are already processed in parallel due to the two independent `supplyAsync` calls. The method `allOf` creates a new future depending on both, which allows you to chain more operations or wait for the completion via `join()`. However, you don’t need to wait for both, as the individual joins (`languages.join()` and `filmCategories.join()`) will wait when needed anyway. More interesting are non-waiting approaches, e.g. `filmCategories.thenCombine(languages, (fc,l) -> ⟨dependent op⟩)`

Comment: @Holger : That was an important point that i was missing completely. Thank You. I am doing this now : filmRepository.findById(filmId)
                .map(e -> {
                    FilmDto f = mapper.filmToFilmDto(e);
                    filmCategories.thenCombine(languages,(fc,ls) -> {
                        f.setLanguageName(ls.get(f.getLanguageId()));
                        f.setFilmCategories(fc.get(f.getFilmId()));
                        return f;
                    });
                    return f;
                })
                .orElse(null);